# Lambda function gets stuck when calling RDS via SQLalchemy URI

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds, fastapi

I have a fast API application. Initially, I was passing my DB URI via ngrok tunnel like this in my SAM template. In this setup Lambda will be using my local machine's PSQL DB.

```yaml
  DbConnnectionString:
    Type: String
   Default: postgresql://<uname>:<pwd>@x.tcp.ngrok.io:PORT/DB
```

This is how I read the URI in my Python code

```py
  # config.py
  DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DB_URI')
  db_engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
  db_session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False,bind=db_engine)
  print(f"Configs initialized for {API_V1_STR}")
```

```py
# app.py

# 3rd party
from fastapi import FastAPI

# Custom
from config.app_config import PROJECT_NAME, db_engine
from models.db_models import Base

print("Creating all database")
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=db_engine)
app = FastAPI(title=PROJECT_NAME)
print("APP created")
```

In this setup, everything seems to work as expected.
[image]

But whenever I replace the DB URL with RDS DB, suddenly the call gets stuck at `create all database` step as shown in the image below. when this happens the lambda always times out and throws exceptions.

- If I run the code locally using uvicorn this error doesn't occur.
  Everything works as expected.
- When I use `sam local invoke` even with RDS URL, the API call works without any issues.

  **This problem occurs only while deployed in AWS Lambda.**

[image]

I notice that configs are initialized twice in this setup, Once before START request ID and once after.

I have tried reading up on it but not clear what could I do to fix this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ever considered Alembic?

Comment: could be your URL format. Have you tried `f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pw}@{url}/{db}'`

Comment: @RakeshAdhikesavan: tried that but the same error exists. I am thinking for some weird reason create_all is called twice and the first call somehow blocks the second call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad!. I didn't pay attention to security groups. It was a connection timeout all along. Once I fixed the port access in Security groups, lambda started working as expected.